# CreateWalletObjectsRequest is missing from com.google.android.gms.wallet API

Tags: android, android-pay

As per the given link: https://developers.google.com/wallet/objects/savetowalletnative

I am trying to run the sample application, but in this below method, I am not able to find `CreateWalletObjectsRequest`. It says:

"CreateWalletObjectsRequest cannot be resolved to a type"

```
public void saveToWallet(View view){

    LoyaltyWalletObject wob = generateObject();


    CreateWalletObjectsRequest request = new CreateWalletObjectsRequest(wob);
    Wallet.createWalletObjects(googleApiClient, request, SAVE_TO_WALLET);

}
```

Comment: Did you create LoyaltyWalletObject? If you create it, please will tell me how you created it? I have had same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467437/saving-offer-to-google-wallet .

Comment: this tutorial is not working https://developers.google.com/wallet/objects/savetowalletnative#obtain_credentials_and_a_client_id_for_your_app

Comment: Was anyone successful importing CreateWalletObjectsRequest?

Answer (score 4):

Google hasn't opened Save to Wallet api for everyone yet. We had to get a special Google Play Services AAR directly from Google, along with a lot of help from a Googler to get it functioning (the sample is out of date).

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you'll need to work with your Google contact to get the second-party library to integrate Android Pay. Once you get the aar file, you can import it into your project and add it as a dependency.

Now, the 'createWalletObjects' method call in your question has shifted in its location and signature; its now as follows:

```
Wallet.WalletObjects.createWalletObjects(googleApiClient, request, SAVE_TO_WALLET);
```

The SAVE_TO_WALLET is the integer request code that you'll identify the request in your `onActivityResult()`. Creating the `request` as such is described in the "Create an object" section of https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/guides/android/add-button-to-your-app

Comment: Hi. Where did you find this part of library?

Comment: @Ihor, When I worked on it during the time, it was a restricted library provided by the Google developer contact to the company I was working for; it wasn't available for all. I'm not sure what the scene is now.